# QLineEdit should accept hexadecimal values ranging from [0 - FFFFF]

Tags: qt

I have a requirement where I want my QLineEdit should accept hexadecimal values ranging from [0 - FFFFF]. can someone help me out with this?

I have tried the below code, but it holds good for only 1 char display.

Comment: You mean only accept hex and between this range?

Comment: you mentioned "below code" -- did you forget to include it?

Comment: Yea, what code?  :)  Do you need a QLineEdit specifically? Because for that range a simple `QSpinBox` re-implementation could take care of it also and perhaps be more user-friendly (increment/decrement with keys/mouse/etc), and has range validation. There might even be an example in the `QSpinBox` Qt docs IIRC.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837961/qt-inputmask-and-qvalidator-for-qlineedit-hex-validation . Though that question has particular validation needs (with the commas), but w/out those needs it would be simpler. But I have to say, I've tried with a mask and validators on a `QLineEdit` and the result is just always awkward to use in some way. I'd use a spin box. You can also look at my [`TimerEdit`](https://github.com/mpaperno/maxLibQt/blob/master/src/widgets/TimerEdit.h) widget which does use a `QLineEdit` instead of a spin box for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in your post, but what you're looking for is a validator, derived from the QValidator class. Create a sub-class, say HexValidator, and implement the "validate" method. You check the input string for the allowed characters and range and return the appropriate state.

You then assign the validator to the QLineEdit using the QLineEdit::setValidator method. Note that the QLineEdit doesn't take ownership of the validator, so you need to make sure you delete it separately or give it a parent so that it gets cleaned up when the parent is deleted. You can create a single validator and assign it to multiple fields if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my comment about Qt docs having a Hex spin box example... so I found one in my archive instead. It could be more flexible, but OTOH it's very simple and short.  I know this isn't a `QLineEdit` but maybe it'll help anyway. The `QValidator` used here could be used in a line edit also.

[image]

```cpp
#ifndef _HEXSPINBOX_H_
#define _HEXSPINBOX_H_

#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QRegularExpressionValidator>

// NOTE: Since QSpinBox uses int as the storage type, the effective editing range
//   is +/- 0x7FFF FFFF, so it can't handle a full unsigned int.  
// QDoubleSpinBox would be a more suitable base class if a wider range is needed.
class HexSpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    HexSpinBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr, 
               bool showPrefix = false, 
               const QString &format = QStringLiteral("%x")) :
      QSpinBox(parent),
      format(format)
    {
      // Validates hex strings up to 8 chars with or w/out leading "0x" prefix.
      // For arbitrary prefix/suffix, the regex could be built dynamically
      //  in validate(), or override setPrefix()/setSuffix() methods.
      const QRegularExpression rx("(?:0[xX])?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}");
      validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rx, this);
      setShowPrefix(showPrefix);
    }

  public slots:
    void setShowPrefix(bool show)
    {
      if (show)
        setPrefix(QStringLiteral("0x"));
      else
        setPrefix(QString());
    }

    void setFormat(const QString &text)
    {
      format = text;
      lineEdit()->setText(textFromValue(value()));
    }

  protected:
    QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int &pos) const override
    {
      return validator->validate(text, pos);
    }

    int valueFromText(const QString &text) const override
    {
      return text.toInt(0, 16);
    }

    QString textFromValue(int value) const override
    {
      return QString().sprintf(qPrintable(format), value);
    }

  private:
    QRegularExpressionValidator *validator;
    QString format;
};

#endif // _HEXSPINBOX_H_
```

Example:

```cpp
#include "HexSpinBox.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QDialog>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QDialog d;
  d.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

  HexSpinBox* sb = new HexSpinBox(&d);
  sb->setMaximum(0xFFFFF);
  sb->setValue(0x0A234);
  d.layout()->addWidget(sb);

  HexSpinBox* sb2 = new HexSpinBox(&d, true, QStringLiteral("%05X"));
  sb2->setMaximum(0xFFFFF);
  sb2->setValue(0x0A234);
  d.layout()->addWidget(sb2);

  return d.exec();
}
```